# i have troubles using beautifulsoup package for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`from bs4 import Beautifulsoup`

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py)

`beautifulsoup` is already installed, yet it keeps returning an error each time I run the codes on my command prompt.

Comment: How do you know it is already installed?

Comment: because i installed it.

Comment: there seems to be "Small Case s" in your import. Try with 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also watch out for the "S" in "Soup". The S should be in capital letter.